# Function calls in Django model class using data from other model class

Tags: django, class, methods, model

I have two model classes and I need to write some logic that uses both. Not sure where I should be adding this logic, and how to implement. This is a highly simplified version;

```
class Yacth(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    adjuster = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Result(models.Model):
    yacht =  models.ForeignKey(Yacht, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result = models.DecimalField(null=TRUE)
    adjusted_result = # I want to populate this field with adjusted result

    def result_adjusted(self):
        a = self.result
        b= self.yacht.adjuster # can I call values from another class like this?
        adjusted_result = (a * b)
        return adjusted_result
```

I need the result to be multiplied by the adjuster as shown in the simple draft method (result_adjusted) above. How can I implement this so that the adjusted result in the model class is populated with the method return?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access the other model through foreign key.
And you could use @property like below:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    yacht =  models.ForeignKey(Yacht, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result = models.DecimalField()

    @property
    def adjusted_result(self):
        return self.result * self.yacht.adjuster
```

After that you'd able to access `Result.objects.first().adjusted_result`

Check out @property usage from official django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Comment: Thanks I looked up the documentation link. It seems that the property is accessible in the same way that any model field would be?

Comment: exactly, actually that is a python feature not a django one.

Comment: Correct. I followed the documentation and it lead me to Python docs. As long as I can access it similar to any model field, I can pass the information into context in the views and to my templates or API.

Comment: I have implemented this successfully, thanks.

However, because my two fields being multiplied are decimal fields (3 decimal places), my results are showing as 6 decimal spaces. Is there any way to convert the output to 3 decimal places?

Comment: Follow up question: In a typical model, the field value that a user adds is saved in the database. Is this the case with properties? Or, do I need to create a separate model class to store the property values?